# Javascript: What does var%20C mean compared to a regular var?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to interpret someone else's code and am very new to Javascript, and I cannot for the life of me find a Javascript tutorial that explains what this means:

```
var%20C = 'ABC...', a=123, b=456, ...;
```

What is var%20C, and how is it different from a regular var?

EDIT: The code is from a bookmarklet.

Comment: It looks like the javascript is urlencoded, which should probably never happen.

Comment: It isn't anything in JavaScript. There's something afoot with the code you're reading.

Comment: The code is from a bookmarklet if that explains anything.

Comment: That does explain it somewhat. %20 is equivalent to a space in a url. Just replace it with a space.

Comment: Downvotes on a legitimate question where the OP saw something and was like "what's going on here?" Sometimes StackOverflow can be harsh. Sorry OP.

Comment: @KevinB It happens when you put your JavaScript into a bookmarklet, and it's what you're supposed to do when you have `<a href="javascript:foo();">`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means the code has gotten mangled. As Kevin B [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29263316/javascript-what-does-var20c-mean-compared-to-a-regular-var#comment46728643_29263316), it looks like it's been partially URL-encoded, which is not a good thing (`%20` in URL encoding = a space).

That should read:

```
var C = 'ABC...', a=123, b=456/*, ...*/;
```

If you asked a JavaScript engine to interpret `var%20C = ...`, it would complain:

> `SyntaxError: Unexpected token %`

Re [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29263316/javascript-what-does-var20c-mean-compared-to-a-regular-var/29263359#comment46728686_29263316):

> The code is from a bookmarklet if that explains anything.

That explains **everything**! The code will be decoded prior to being run, so the `%20` will turn back into a space before the JavaScript engine sees it.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out, the code is url encoded.

You can url decode it and turn it back to "normal" like so:

```
decodeURIComponent("var%20C = 'ABC...', a=123, b=456;");
```

If you are **100% sure that the string you are evaluating is trusted and safe** (read: if you wrote it) you can run it like this:

```
eval(decodeURIComponent("var%20C = 'ABC...', a=123, b=456;"));
```

After that, the variables `C`, `a` and `b` will be initialized.

Please keep in mind though that **`eval` is dangerous** and **considered "evil"** when you can't be 100% sure that the string you are evaluating is trusted and safe.

Comment: <3 the last note, regarding you just told him to do it on a bookmarklet script (so probably ugllified and found anywhere) code that OP doesn't understand (stated  `am very new to Javascript`and doesn't know `%20`is space)

Comment: @Kaiido Indeed :) Take it as a technical pointer of how to make url-encoded JS code runnable. This in no way implies that you SHOULD do this :)

Comment: Let me refer you to http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice I've edited my answer to make the warning more prominent.